# removing an object via hibernate and it's fails

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

i can't erase the code object directly with the REmover class...and it gives me an error...
but when i first deleting the joined comment with my code then remove the code it's done...
is there any other way to do the deleting comments of the code and the code object automaticly?
with regards...

> WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503
>   Jun 24, 2013 2:25:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
>   ERROR: ERROR: update or delete on table "code" violates foreign key constraint "fk_evs9qdyt93ms7uvl3ud2nwy71" on table "comments"
>     Detail: Key (codeid)=(14) is still referenced from table "comments".
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)

```
@Entity
public class Userdetails{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long userid;
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String username;
private String password;
private String fname;
private String lname;
private String email;
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Code.class, mappedBy="userdetails")
private List<Code> codes;
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Messages.class, mappedBy="SMS")
private List<Messages> messages;

public List<Messages> getMessages() {
    return messages;
}
public void setMessages(List<Messages> messages) {
    this.messages = messages;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}
public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}
public String getLname() {
    return lname;
}
public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public List<Code> getCodes() {
    return codes;
}
public void setCodes(List<Code> codes) {
    this.codes = codes;
}

public Userdetails(String username, String password, String fname, String lname,     String email) {
    super();
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.email = email;
}
public Userdetails() {
    super();
}
public static boolean updateUserDetails(Object current) {
    return UserDBHandler.updateObject(current);
}
public static boolean setUserDetails(Userdetails user) {
    return UserDBHandler.saveObject(user);
}
public static Userdetails getUserDetails(String username, String password) {
    return UserDBHandler.loadUser(username, password);
}
public static boolean isUser(String username,String passw0rd) {
    return UserDBHandler.isUser(username,passw0rd);
}
public static boolean LogoutUser() {
    return UserDBHandler.LogoutUser();
}


}



package UsersProperty;

@Entity
public class Code {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int codeId;
private int Rating;
private int NORaters;
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String fileName;
private String OwnerName;
private String PrjName;
private String CodeLang;
private String Tags;
    private String Tags2;
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="userid")
private Userdetails userdetails;
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Comments.class, mappedBy="targetCode")
private List<Comments> cm;

public int getCodeId() {
    return codeId;
}
public void setCodeId(int codeId) {
    this.codeId = codeId;
}
public int getNORaters() {
    return NORaters;
}
public void setNORaters(int nORaters) {
    NORaters = nORaters;
}
public int getRating() {
    return Rating;
}
public void setRating(int rating) {
    Rating = rating;
}

public List<Comments> getCm() {
    return cm;
}
public void setCm(List<Comments> cm) {
    this.cm = cm;
}
public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}
public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public String getOwnerName() {
    return OwnerName;
}
public void setOwnerName(String ownerName) {
    OwnerName = ownerName;
}

public String getPrjName() {
    return PrjName;
}
public void setPrjName(String prjName) {
    PrjName = prjName;
}

public String getCodeLang() {
    return CodeLang;
}
public void setCodeLang(String codeLang) {
    CodeLang = codeLang;
}
public String getTags() {
    return Tags;
}
public void setTags(String tags) {
    Tags = tags;
}
    public String getTags2() {
    return Tags2;
}
public void setTags2(String tags2) {
    Tags2 = tags2;
}
public Userdetails getUserdetails() {
    return userdetails;
}
public void setUserdetails(Userdetails userdetails) {
    this.userdetails = userdetails;
}
public Code(String fileName, String ownerName, String prjName,String Lang,String     tAgs,String tAgs2) {
    super();
    this.fileName = fileName;
    OwnerName = ownerName;
    PrjName = prjName;
    Tags=tAgs;
            Tags2=tAgs2;
    CodeLang = Lang;
}
public Code() {
    super();
}

public static void CodeSearch(String TAGS){
        SpecificCodeSearchDBHandler.searchCodeTags(TAGS);
}
    public static Code LoadCode(String Path){
    return CodePathLoaderDBHandler.loadCode(Path);
}
public static String FNameExtractor(String FilePath){
    String Fname = null;
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner Reader = new Scanner(FilePath);
    Reader.useDelimiter("/");
    while(Reader.hasNext())
    Fname = Reader.next();
    return Fname;

}
}



package UsersProperty;


@Entity
public class Comments {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int cmId;
private String Cm;
private String Cmplacer;
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="codeId")
private Code targetCode;

public Comments() {
}

public String getCm() {
    return Cm;
}
public void setCm(String cm) {
    Cm = cm;
}
public String getCmplacer() {
    return Cmplacer;
}
public void setCmplacer(String cmplacer) {
    Cmplacer = cmplacer;
}
public Code getTargetCode() {
    return targetCode;
}
public void setTargetCode(Code targetCode) {
    this.targetCode = targetCode;
}
public Comments(String cm, String cmplacer) {
    super();
    Cm = cm;
    Cmplacer = cmplacer;
}

}




public class REmover {
private static Session scss;
private static SessionFactory sfactory;
static {
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Userdetails.class);
    cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Code.class);
    cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Messages.class);
    cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Comments.class);
    cfg.configure();
    new SchemaExport(cfg);
    sfactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

}
public static boolean removeCode(Object object) {
    try {
        scss = sfactory.openSession();
        scss.beginTransaction();
        scss.delete(object);
                    scss.getTransaction().commit();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        scss.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add the appropriate cascade operation to your @OneToMany, e.g.

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Comments.class, mappedBy="targetCode", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
```

have a look at the API:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#cascade()

and:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html